# Mapbox map rendering issue

Tags: python-3.x, mapbox, mapbox-api-tilequery

I’m using the Mapbox Upload API to stage my data into tilesets. I also use the style API to apply dynamic styling to these tilsets and generate choropleth maps (among other things).
I recently came across some glitches in the rendering of those maps.
I build geometry object (geojson) representing an area and store in the geojson object properties the statistic for that area (the statistics are then used to generate color scales).

The glitches I am referring to are weird, curved lines on the sides of the geometrical shapes I generate (instead of square shaped geometries, with straight side lines).
I think it might be important to note that the issue occurs only for a certain type of geometry objects (geohash, s3 and h3 work fine, but insee cells aren’t)
another information potentially useful to have, is that without styling, no issue. the shapes are rendered correctly with no bending. Which makes think that there might be some parameter that modifies the projection of those geometries on the map... Is this assertion correct?

Here is a screenshot of the same geometric data with and without styling.

[image: with styling on the left.]

[image]

Please let me know if this is a know issue.
Thanks